# Is there any applied exposition of the Kahn-Kalai conjecture?

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, statistical-mechanics

In [the Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahn%E2%80%93Kalai_conjecture) associated with the Kahn-Kalai conjecture, there is the following assertion

> This conjecture concerns the general problem of estimating when phase
> transitions occur in systems.

As this entry notes, the conjecture (technically "theorem", as is recently proved) is

> in the field of graph theory and statistical mechanics

I am particularly interested in the consequences of this conjecture in view of statistical mechanics and (even if possible) its implications and applications to formation of complex networks in engineering fields. [The main article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0603218.pdf), as far as I can see, heavily focuses on graph-theoretic facets of the conjecture. So, is there any applied exposition of this conjecture?